# How to know when to stop practice under symptomatic allergic rhinitis

Tags: running, endurance

I skipped one half marathon because of my too high levels of IgE in blood.
The reason was that I was not sure if I can do it under such condition.
I was also not sure about when to stop if something comes.
Last year, I did run under allergic symptoms but my recovery time was exceptionally very long.

I felt very good during running however.
When I stopped, I felt exhausted and after it in recovering.
The marathon also put my immune system little down and caused me some opportunistic diseases which I do not normally get.

I am interested in how you can support your immune system in running and in recovering from running.

I took pseudoefedrine before running and decreased the antihistamine load.
I think I ate too little days after running which may be one reason for long recovery time.

**What is a good strategy for endurance sport with allergic symptoms before and after the attempt?**